# xib using autolayout not showing when added as subview

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, constraints, xib

I had an `UIViewController`**A** created with xib for view reusability.

In the xib I simply added another red view to it and set its constraints to top,leading,trailing, and bottom space to red view's superview (which is my A's view).

Add **A** to another `UIViewController` **B** as **B**'s `ChildViewController` by doing so:

```
// UIViewControllerB.m

UIViewControllerA *A = [UIViewControllerA alloc] initWithNibName:@"UIViewControllerA" bundle: nil]];
[A.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.size.width, self.view.size.height/2)];
[self addChildViewController:A];
[self.view addSubview:A.view];
[self.A didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Nothing red or whatever showed up.

I did try  `[self.A.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];` though
that seemed to make my constraints useless and actually did not bring up the red view.

Do I have to code the whole thing (UI elements & constraints creation) when I'm working with xib and need some extra view with autolayout?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Please start by proving that UIViewControllerA is actually loading its xib file and getting its view there.

Comment: @matt load nib when init it. see the edited code plz.

Comment: If the bigger view in the UIViewControllerA.xib is some weird color like yellow, do you see _that_? In other words, let's find out if what's missing is the little red view or the whole thing.

Comment: @matt I set the red view's height & width as same as it's superview. It's weird that only if I did add no constraints to a subview (label, button, view ...) did one appear but without proper position. And if I code everything it works fine!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794718/xcode-weird-issue-with-xib-and-auto-layout-xib-expands-to-random-height answer of this question seemed to prove my assumption ... xib did not work great with autolayout.

Comment: Okay, I understand the cause now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
[A.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.size.width, self.view.size.height/2)];
```

Instead, give this view *constraints*.

When you insert a set of views that uses autolayout into a set of views that uses autolayout, you must use autolayout to position it.

Comment: well guess I was wrong .. is's not xib doesn't work with autolayout, but those constraints cannot be run well  before compiler knows who the superview is, which means it knows the basic reliance of those constraints. Thanks @matt =)